# Enable/Disable button by selected value in drop down list using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-controller

I have one button called test and one drop-down menu with three values.
How to enable-disable Test button according to value selected in drop down menu.
Eg. If selected "Not Ready" , button should disable
    If selected Ready or Attention, button should enable

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
    <button id="testBtn" class="btn btn-default" >Test</button>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">


    <select name="select">
        <option value="value1" selected>Not ready</option> 
        <option value="value2">Ready</option>
        <option value="value3">Attention !!</option>
    </select>


 </div>
</div>
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/suRIVHWECXYdtYy5tbbd)

Comment: And what have you tried? Your example has neither an angular app, nor a controller. Just straight-up HTML.

Comment: sorry !! New to AngularJs !!

Comment: It's ok to be new to it. But you need to actually *try* to do it first instead of just asking someone else to write your code for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an Angular app and controller. From there you can bind a model to your select, and then use an expression with the ng-disabled directive on the button to enable and disable it dynamically depending on the value in the box.
See below. ng-model on the select binds it to $scope.currentState which is what I compare my literal string against in the ng-disabled directive on the button.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.states = ['Not ready', 'Ready', 'Attention !!'];
  $scope.currentState = 'Not ready';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS App</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <button id="testBtn" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="currentState === 'Not ready'">Test</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


      <select name="select" ng-model="currentState" ng-options="state as state for state in states">
      </select>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the validation value is number then use this method.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <label class="control-label  col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">User Type</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <select class="form-control height_30" ng-model="data1.user_type " ng-options="cust.id as cust.typename for cust in usertype"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <label class="control-label  col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data1.user_passwd">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            <label class="control-label  col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Customer</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <select ng-disabled="data1.user_type === 1 || data1.user_type === 2" class="form-control height_30" ng-model="data1.customer_id" ng-options="cust.customer_id as cust.customer_name for cust in customers"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="a.name for a in data">
    <option value="">
        select
    </option></select>
<button class="btnS btn-success ctrl-btn" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="!item"> Submit</button>
```